Using pyrcc5 when OSGeo4W is not installed on C:
I am writing a plugin from QGIS that I started up using plugin builder. On a previous system my OSGeo4W was on my C: and I also had an older version of QGIS (v3.26), and I generated the resource files using pyrcc5 when I was using that system. I have since moved computers, and on my current PC, my C: drive is only a very small startup drive, as such I install all of my non-system programmes on my D: drive. I therefore have OSGeo4W as well as QGIS3.34 installed on my D: drive.
I need to change the icon for my plugin. As such, I need to re-compile my resource files. I have an IDE set up with the following batch file:
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass83\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass83\lib
path %PATH%;D:\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python312
start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B "D:\apps\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.4\bin\pycharm64.exe" %*


Within the IDE cmd, I can run pb_tool succesfully, and have succesfully removed the old resources.py file. I now want to generate a new one. I already had a compile.bat file, which contained:
@echo off
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc

I changed all of these to refer to D:
@echo off
call "D:\OSGeo4W\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "D:\OSGeo4W\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "D:\OSGeo4W\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc

Running this causes the following error and traceback:
Compiled 0 UI files
Compiling resources.qrc to resources.py
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python3.exe"  "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Scripts\pyrcc5.EXE" -o resources.py resources.qrc': The system cannot find the file specified.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Scripts\pb_tool.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pb_tool\pb_tool.py", line 338, in compile
    compile_files(get_config(config))
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pb_tool\pb_tool.py", line 996, in compile_files
    subprocess.check_call([pyrcc5, '-o', output, res])
  File "D:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python312\\Scripts\\pyrcc5.EXE', '-o', 'resources.py', 'resources.qrc']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

According to the third line, pb_tool is still trying to find Python in OSGeo4W on my C: drive. I cannot find where to change this; My understanding of batch files is rudimentary at best. I have tried adding a path to the correct location of OSGeo4W by adding the following lines to start of compile.bat:
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python312

But this did not change anything. How do I make pyrcc5 refer to the correct location?
